# Upload Large Files using php?

Tags: php, file-upload

I need to upload a large file (up to 190mb)
Here is server details for limit:

```
memory_limit = 50M
post_max_size = 192M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 192M 
max_execution_time = 1800 sec
max_input_time = 1800 sec
```

Here is my code:

```
 $query="update tbl_Cards set CardName='$cardname',Description='$Description'";
    if($cardvideo)
    {
      if($_FILES["cardvideo"]["type"] == "video/quicktime"||$_FILES["cardvideo"]["type"] == "video/mov"||$_FILES["cardvideo"]["type"] == "video/mp4"||$_FILES["cardvideo"]["type"] == "video/mpv"||$_FILES["cardvideo"]["type"] == "video/3gp")
      {
        if($_FILES["cardvideo"]["size"]<=10485760)
        {
          $cardvideo=$date."card.mp4";
          $tmppath3="services/video/".$cardvideo;
          if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cardvideo']['tmp_name'],$tmppath3))
          {
          $thumb=$date.".jpg";
          $thumbDirectory="services/VideoCapturePic/";
          exec("convert \"{$tmppath3}[0]\" -colorspace RGB -geometry 200 $thumbDirectory$thumb");
          $query.=",Video='$cardvideo',CapturePic='$thumb'";
        }
        $query.="where CardId='$card'";

        $result=mysql_query($query);
        if($result)
        {
        } else
        {
        echo mysql_error();
        }
```

But when I upload 10 mb files they upload successfully but when I try to upload large files (20 or 30 or 40 or 50) I get this response:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row this my error message

Comment: That error has no relation with the file size but with ONE query that is going out with an empty field, so it goes short by one field... must depurate your file (sorry but that's it). Split it into parts so you can isolate the defective data... maybe something with an apostrophe (') that ends prematurely the query

Comment: ok just i am posting sample code but i when i upload 10 mb file upload successfully upload lagre file i get this problem so i think time expire to upload file then script terminate

Comment: @Alfabravo: How does one "depurate" a file?

Comment: @Gabe Being a bulk update, the idea is to have appropiate data (in a ETL-like process), rightly formatted. A script validating data being inserted could help, for example. The responsability goes over the one who produces the file.

Answer (score 1):

Its not just the php.ini, but server also can restrict your request size. Though by default in apache its not set to limit the file size, but I think you should check for that once. LimitRequestBody directive is used to restrict the request size. Check for the directive in all your configuration files (I am assuming that you are using apache) and change the value for your directory.
Sample usage:

```
<Directory "/var/www/vhost/mydir/uploads">
    LimitRequestBody 204444344
</Directory>
```

Comment: i am using ftp for server connect

Comment: how can i check ftp details limit in ftp

Comment: HI i am using linux server how can i check limitRequestBody in my server

Comment: this is not about the OS on your server, its about the we server you are using. e.g. apache/ weblogic etc. So you need to check configuration there.

Comment: yes..i am using Apache server so how can i change  limitRequestBody in my server please tell me clearly

Comment: in your apache configuration files, search for the 'directory' you are currently working in, and then in between the tags place LimitRequestBody . 
Apache configuration files location is generally
/etc/httpd/conf or similar
/etc/apache2/conf or similar.

Comment: yes..i increase "/www/admin/VueGuides/services/video" path 2 GB but same result how can i check is it applying or not