# 500 internal server error - uploading large files - PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, plesk

I am making a video file uploader using PHP and html5. But I am getting a 500 internal server error and sometimes connection timeout error (err_connection_reset), if I upload a file with a size more than around 100mb. It works fine for smaller files.
maybe server timeout issue. IDK!
I have tried these to increase file upload limits:

```
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
memory_limit = 1024M
post_max_size = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
```

but still it gives me the same error for larger files. I have echoed these values and they are all correctly loading. Are there some other values that i should change?. I am hosting my website at Plesk Hosting (economy pack)
can anyone help!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload Large Files using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830322/upload-large-files-using-php)

Comment: Please give more information about the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing your php.ini directly, you shouldn't use quotes around the settings. Also make sure that the ini-file is loaded, you can check this by using:

```
echo php_ini_loaded_file();
```